# Create a new page on front page for logged in user

Tags: rest-api, wp-insert-post

I am going to find a way for logged in users to create pages from front page. For example there are three buttons so called button1,2,3. When logged in users clicks on button1, a page with title newyork1 is created and if user clicks on New York button for one more time, a new page newyork1-1 and newyork1-2 are created and the same logical with Tokyo and London. I have tried Wordpress Rest API then wp_insert_post() function but it not working as it cannot get the author and title as i aspected. If you guys have a better idea, please help. Thank you

```
<ul> 
    <li> <a href="" data-name="newyork"> New York</a></li> 
    <li> <a href="" data-name="tokyo"> Tokyo</a></li>
    <li> <a href="" data-name="london"> London</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @Tony, your question is too vague and not appropriate for this forum, you are unlikely to get any answers.  You are seeking to solutions to your specific problem, and not to a general WP functionality problem.  Questions which have a real value for the rest of the community (ie that others may face too) are more likely to get you answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about redirecting specific users with a set of redirect rules? You can try using [Peter’s Login Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) plugin. Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate the plugin.
2. Hover on **Settings** in the left sidebar.
3. Click on **Login/logout redirects**.
4. Enter your custom Login URL for specific users.

Answer (score 0):

Already has a solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/312346/76587)
You have modify a bit to use it.
1. 'post_type'   => 'post', change to 'post_type'   => 'page',

Also your user must have capabilities to create page. Here is another [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188889/76587) on how to handle that.