# Preview post on frontend before submitting it?

Tags: front-end, previews

I found a related (old)post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/311564/front-end-form-to-create-a-custom-post-with-preview)

I'm currently using usp pro as a frontend.

I'm creating a free pet memorial site, and want the user to just fill out the form, (NO ACCOUNT REQUIRED),and the post is created, which works fine without any issues. **BUT** there isn't any options to preview the post, only submit it.

I really want to give the users many design options, but a preview function are required, but I'm not an expert in php, and certainly not in WordPress.

Anybody that knows anything about this?